# How to specify that two wildcards are semantically equal in a non-generic method?

Tags: java, generics

I am currently trying to follow the Drag&Drop tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dropmodedemo.html).

Sadly the example code does not particularly care about being free of warnings, whereas I would prefer my own code to be clean.

I wish to implement the importData method from that page within the following context:

```
class Base;
class Wrapper<T extends Base>;
class SelectionList<T extends Base> extends JList<Wrapper<T>>;
```

To that end, I produced the following code:

```
public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support)
{
  if(this.canImport(support))
  {
    Transferable t = support.getTransferable();
    SelectionList list = (SelectionList)support.getComponent();
    JList.DropLocation location = list.getDropLocation();
    Wrapper<? extends Base> o;
    try{ o = (Wrapper<? extends Base>)t.getTransferData(SelectionList.flavour); }
    catch(Exception e) { return false; }

    int index = location.getIndex();
    if(location.isInsert())
      ((DefaultListModel)list.getModel()).add(index, o);
    //else link

    return true;
  }
  else
    return false;
}
```

Work in progress, obviously.

At this point, I get a warning on

`((DefaultListModel<Wrapper<?>)list.getModel()).add(index, o);`:

```
unchecked call to add(int,E) as a member of the raw type javax.swing.DefaultListModel
```

No surprise that.

I have been trying several approaches to fix this; (note how I already solved the similar, simpler problem in case of variable o):

```
SelectionList<?> list = (SelectionList<?>)support.getComponent();
// [...]
  ((DefaultListModel<Wrapper<?>)list.getModel()).add(index, o);
```

yields

```
unchecked cast
  required: javax.swing.DefaultListModel<Wrapper<?>>
  found:    javax.swing.ListModel<Wrapper<capture#1 of ?>>
```

Aka it treats the two wildcards as different sets of possibilities.

```
SelectionList<? extends Base> list = (SelectionList<? extends Base>)support.getComponent();
// [...]
  ((DefaultListModel<Wrapper<? extends Base>)list.getModel()).add(index, o);
```

same here:

```
unchecked cast
  required: javax.swing.DefaultListModel<Wrapper<? extends Base>>
  found:    javax.swing.ListModel<Wrapper<capture#1 of ? extends Base>>
```

***How can I specify that the types in question satisfy the definition of SelectionList*** and therefore the cast ***is not*** unchecked?

- I would have assumed that this were obvious, after all it is **defined**, an axiom, automatically true in all possible worlds, but the compiler disagrees. Even though it works perfectly fine for variable o (and the initialisation of variable list), where the generic types are equal, not one nested into the other.

I have to no avail read the, linked to in related questions, [guide here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html), but it seems to contradict itself in several places; notably it seems to at once claim that

- the approaches I tried are both perfectly fine and neither should actually produce a warning
- the solution for variable o is just as impossible as the solution I seek here

Both are obviously incorrect; probably my own misunderstanding to blame.

---

Trying to follow @Peter_Lawrey I put up this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support)
{
  if(this.canImport(support))
  {
    Transferable t = support.getTransferable();
    SelectionList list = (SelectionList)support.getComponent();
    Wrapper o;
    try{ o = (Wrapper)t.getTransferData(SelectionList.flavour); }
    catch(Exception e) { return false; }

    importIt((DefaultListModel<Wrapper>)list.getModel(), list.getDropLocation(), o);

    return true;
  }
  else
    return false;
}

public <T extends Base> void importIt(DefaultListModel<Wrapper<T>> model, JList.DropLocation location, Wrapper<T> o)
{
  if(location.isInsert())
    model.add(location.getIndex(), o);
  //else link
}
```

Hoping that this would do it. It would have the advantage that importData could be put into an intermediate class extending TransferHandler, from which all further TransferHandlers could extend themselves, overriding only importIt - which needs not be annotated.

However this produces an error:

```
method importIt in class imise.app.SelectionList.SelectionListTransferHandler cannot be applied to given types;
  required: javax.swing.DefaultListModel<imise.app.OntologyMemberWrap<T>>,javax.swing.JList.DropLocation,imise.app.OntologyMemberWrap<T>
  found: javax.swing.DefaultListModel<imise.app.OntologyMemberWrap>,javax.swing.JList.DropLocation,imise.app.OntologyMemberWrap
  reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that argument type javax.swing.DefaultListModel<imise.app.OntologyMemberWrap> conforms to formal parameter type javax.swing.DefaultListModel<imise.app.OntologyMemberWrap<T>>
```

And no different, if adding wildcards in the call (same problem as in the beginning).

Looks I have to specify the inner generic explicitly. So I would need to make importData generic. Then it does no longer override TransferHandler.importData (which it has to).
... Or I guess, just annotating **all the methods** with `@suppressWarnings("unchecked")` would do it as well; I would prefer a proper solution but it looks a lot as if there existed none (would be glad to be proven wrong).

Answer (score 3):

You have to give it generic name like `T extends Base` and then everywhere you use `T` will be equal. Two unknowns are not implicitly the same.

To have a "local" generic you can extract a method like this.

```
public <T extends Base> void method() throws Exception {
    Wrapper<T> o = (Wrapper<T>) t.getTransferData(SelectionList.flavour);
    int index = location.getIndex();
    if(location.isInsert())
         ((DefaultListModel<Wrapper<T>>)list.getModel()).add(index, o);
}
```

Comment: That makes the method itself generic though, does it not? I might be mistaken about that, coming from a C++ background, but would this not mean that the method itself is generic, so would create warnings if not used with a T parameter? Then the warning would only have moved.

Comment: Also does not seem to work: The `unchecked cast` travels to `SelectionList<T> list = (SelectionList<T>)support.getComponent();` and also to `o = (Wrapper<T>)t.getTransferData(SelectionList.flavour);` (which cannot be avoided, as that would cause conversion error on `((DefaultListModel<Wrapper<T>>)list.getModel()).add(index, o);
`); this has then to be resolved via wildcard `SelectionList<? extends T>`, restoring the original problem. ... At least as far as I can see.

Comment: @Zsar it moves the problem to the method but provide equivalence for the `T` values which is what you asked for. An unchecked cast is a warning, not an error. It means the compiler cannot validate the cast you have used. The best option being to avoid needing the cast in the first place by making the generic of the fields used correct.

Comment: Well, the casts cannot be avoided; the API methods in question return Object and JComponent - both free of generics. - Am I merely casting wrong? Obviously, a warning-free piece of code is my goal, I may have been wrong in assuming that the obvious-_seeming_ method is possible and/or easy to accomplish.

Comment: Furthermore, putting a generic parameter into the method declaration is impossible: It creates a name clash with TransferHandler.importData - which this method is supposed to override.

Comment: @Zsar there is no way to tell the compiler that a cast from raw type to `X<Y>` is 100% safe. It will always produce a warning, unless you turn it off with `@SuppressWarning("checked")`

Comment: @Zsar so if you can't fix the source types. I suggest creating a simple method to do the cast where you add the suppress warning annotation and your code will compile without warnings.

Comment: Added yet another failed attempt to the OP. It just does not work out, does it? Always back to the original problem, if for different reasons. This looks like a fundamental flaw in the language. Should I just throw out generics and call it a day?

Comment: @Zsar don't assume it will solve all your problems especially when you can't fix the cause of the problem in the first place,

Comment: I ended up disabling the warning wherever it cropped up and, at large, ignoring the issue. Other similar questions seem to indicate that **_there is no proper solution_**. Figured that this would change at some point, but evidently it has not yet.